Browser is showing Sign in window for some URLs only
I have a PHP app on IIS 10.
Recently some pages started displaying the Sign in window asking for username and password:

What could cause that? Only Windows Authentication is Enabled with "HTTP 401 Challenge" and it only shows in certain pages. For most pages everything works well and doesn't show that popup window.
For example, https://example.com/some-url/ would work without the window, but https://example.com/some-url/sub-url would display it

A picture of the configuration would have been more helpful than a picture of a login prompt.

thank you. do you have a specific configuration I should upload? I am not sure which (because it's been working till now, so I have no idea which configuration might cause that)

Can you open IIS log files and see if you get 401.3/401.5 for sub-url requests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#log-file-locations
